# Error when I want to display list of account when checkbox is checked

Tags: lightning-web-components, error, checkbox

*ShowAcct.cls*

```
public with sharing class ShowAcct {
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> getAccountList() {
        return [SELECT id,name,AnnualRevenue from Account];
    }
}
```

*showAcctRecordswithCheckbox.html*

```html
<template>
    <lightning-input type="checkbox"
                     label="Show/Hide"
                     checked={showFields}
                     onchange={toggleFields}>
    </lightning-input>
    <template if:true={showFields}>
        <template if:true={accList}>
            <lightning-datatable 
                    data ={acctList}  
                    columns={columns} 
                    key-field="id" >
            </lightning-datatable>  
        </template>
    </template>    
    <template if:true={error}>
        {error}
    </template>
</template>
```

*showAcctRecordswithCheckbox.html*

```js
import { LightningElement,api,wire,track} from 'lwc';
import getAccountList from '@salesforce/apex/ShowAcct.getAccountList';

export default class ShowAcctRecordswithCheckbox extends LightningElement {
    showFields = true;
    @track columns;
    
    toggleFields() {
        this.showFields = !this.showFields;
        columns=[{
            label:'Account Name',
            fieldName: 'Name',
            type:'text',
            sortable:true
        },{
            label:'Annual Revenue',
            type:'Currency',
            fieldName:'Annual Revenue',
            sortable:true
        }];
    }

    @track accList;
    
    @wire(getAccountList)
    wiredAccounts({error,data}) {
        if(data){
            this.accList = data;
        } else if(error){
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
}
```

Class is successfully deployed but it shows only checked checkbox ...no fields and as soon as i unchecked it it shows error
`SORRY TO INTURUPPT`

`This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: -465312255)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I found typos in code:

- `data = {acctList}` and in js code: `accList`
- `fieldName: "Annual Revenue",` should be `fieldName: "AnnualRevenue"`

Additionally you not need `@track` decorator as you reassign whole objects.

Corrected code:

*showAcctRecordswithCheckbox.html*

```html
<template>
    <lightning-input type="checkbox" 
                     label="Show/Hide" 
                     checked={showFields} 
                     onchange={toggleFields}> 
    </lightning-input>
    <template if:true={showFields}>
        <template if:true={accList}>
            <lightning-datatable data={accList} 
                                 columns={columns} 
                                 key-field="id">
            </lightning-datatable>
        </template>
    </template>
    <template if:true={error}> {error} </template>
</template>
```

*showAcctRecordswithCheckbox.js*

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import getAccountList from "@salesforce/apex/ShowAcct.getAccountList";

export default class ShowAcctRecordswithCheckbox extends LightningElement {
    accList;
    showFields = true;
    columns = [
        {
            label: "Account Name",
            fieldName: "Name",
            type: "text",
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            label: "Annual Revenue",
            type: "Currency",
            fieldName: "AnnualRevenue",
            sortable: true
        }
    ];

    toggleFields() {
        this.showFields = !this.showFields;
    }

    @wire(getAccountList)
    wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.accList = data;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You So Much